# python print function using line break where not supposed to in for loop

Tags: python, printing

I have:

```
for emp_id,pay_rate,job_num1,hours_worked1,job_numb2,hours_worked2,job_num3,hours_worked3,job_numb4,hours_worked4,job_numb5,hours_worked5 in master_list:
        print('Job Number:', job_num1, 'Employee Id:', emp_id, 'Hours Worked:', hours_worked1, 'Hourly Rate:', pay_rate, 'Gross Pay:', int(pay_rate) * int(hours_worked1), sep ='')
```

This loop is pulling the values from a nested loop.
I am getting:

```
Job Number:963789Employee Id:001Hours Worked:40
Hourly Rate:15
Gross Pay:600
```

...etc.

Why is the Hourly Rate and Gross Pay  appearing on a new lines? Shouldn't they appear as part of the whole single line? I am just looking for a simple solution

Comment: Can you show us `master_list` and what it contains?

Comment: Because there are `\n` in `hours_worked1`, `job_numb2` - I saw this data in previous question - use `hours_worked1.strip()`, `job_numb2.strip()` in `print`.

Comment: Duhh how dumb of me. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, that uses string formatting, and also some logic since each record you have consists of three items.

```
s = 'Job Number:{0} Employee Id: {1} Hours Worked: {2} Hourly Rate: {3} Gross Pay: {4}'
record_size = 3  # Each record consists of three items

for record in master_list:
    record = map(str.strip, record) # Removes whitespace
    for i in xrange(0, len(record), record_size):
        bits = record[i:i+record_size]
        jnum, empid, hours, rate = bits
        gross_pay = int(rate) * int(hours)
        print(s.format(jnum, empid, hours, rate, gross_pay), sep='')
```